# FB change share location

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I make "In a private message" value by default? I think this value affects "action_type", found only this example:

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.likes',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    })
  })
```

[share dialog](https://monosnap.com/file/mjop8LCg7TnX3aHJLClqK3YbXFSdc9)

I know about `FB.ui({method: 'send'})`, but I need share dialog with "In a private message" by default.